# s_gi not defined for Adobe Analytics when loading Analytics libraries from Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I want to add customized code in HTML pages that use Adobe Analytics. I am loading the Adobe Analytics using Adobe DTM, but the customized analytics code does not work:

- Page: http://tru.am/scripts/pages/fb.instant.articles.002.adobe.analytics.web.html
- The Analytics trigger and I see the page view, no problem with that
- The issue is when I add the customized code:

```js
< body>
      <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var s_account="museplatamerptrsdtemplate";
        var s = s_gi(s_account);
        s.pageName="Test for FIA - Adobe Analytics 002"
    
        s.prop1="TRUE ANTHEM page"
        s.prop2="Web Page, Desktop"
        s.prop3="TRU.AM Domain"
        s.prop4=""
        s.prop5=""
        /* Conversion Variables */
    
        /* s.campaign=""
        s.state=""
        s.zip=""
        s.events=""
        s.products=""
        s.purchaseID=""
        s.eVar1=""
        s.eVar2=""
        s.eVar3=""
        s.eVar4=""
        s.eVar5="" */
        s.eVar1=""
        s.eVar2="Web Page, Desktop"
        s.eVar3="TRU.AM Domain"
    
        var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
      
    ...
```

- The error I get is that the `s_gi` function is not defined:

  `Uncaught ReferenceError: s_gi is not defined
      at fb.instant.articles.002.adobe.analytics.web.html:46`
- But DTM is loading the library on `http://assets.adobedtm.com/4fd579a8bf542838e76bfff27dfe696fdc4b3df8/s-code-contents-f2908a5893037bc0933bbe024dfe4477fbd0c725.js`, where `s_gi` is defined
- What is wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make full use of the features in DTM please. Shift your customised page codes in the Adobe Analytics tool's [Customize Page Code](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/customize_page_code.html) section.

If the customised page codes is for an one-off page, you might want to set up a [page load rule](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/rules_page.html) and set the values in the Adobe Analytics tool section in the page load rule.

If the customised page codes is to test for a template setup, you might want to explore using [datalayers](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/data-layer/), [Data Elements](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/data_elements.html) and the [Global Variables](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/global_variables.html) in the Adobe Analytics tool base setup.

Answer (score 0):

Please place DTM container snippet over customize code in your webpage and make sure these custom variables are not again overridden in DTM